# Can anyone recommend me a software that I could use for writing a character's draft and planning a script?

Tags: windows, text-editor

users!

I need a program that I can use for making such drafts like this, for example:
[image: John Smith, aka Doctor]

I’m trying to come up with a detailed story for a book, but it’sn’t just going to keep so many characters in my head: what they like, how long they can keep air in the water and other information. I made the photo above in Photoshop, but I need a program that makes it possible to create such scenarios and save them as documents and not photos.

Comment: There have been quite a few similar questiosn E.g. [this one](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21198/software-for-writing-novels). i don't have time to search the site for you, so just search for obvious keywords, Good luck :-)

Comment: @Mawg thank you. I'll try some of these softwares.

Comment: Like I said, search this site; there have been multiple such questions, not just that one. Good luck :0(